# How to integrate in app subscription in android studio?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription, android-studio-3.0, google-play-console

I am new to in app subscription. I have looked at Google's official documentation but that wasn't helpful. In my app I want to integrate monthly in app subscription. There are no proper tutorials for subscription on YouTube either, there are only for one time in app products. All I know is that I need a product Id and license key for in app purchases and I have them both with me. Can anyone help me with subscription? Here is my code

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{

BillingProcessor bp;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, Constants.base64EncodedPublicKey, this);
        
bp.purchase(MainSellerActivity.this,"subscription_product_id");        
        }
        
        
        @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Subscribed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {

    }
```

The provided code above is a little bit modified, but this is basically where I am stuck at. Everything is working fine with when I use android.test.purchased in place of product Id, but I am getting an error when I use an actual product Id. Please help. If possible please provide a complete code for subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library.it is easy to integrate 
[android-inapp-billing-v3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)

Comment: Followed all the instructions and I am getting an error: This version of application is not configured for billing